# Rails: Any way to get multiple first/last records of one-many models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model, and User model has_many :roles.

Say I have 1000 Users' record in the database, is there a way to obtain the first/last record of the roles for each User's record? i.e what I would like to achieve is to retrieve user.roles.first or user.roles.last for each User's record.

I could do something like

```
User.all.each do |u|
    puts u.roles.first # or u.roles.last
end
```

but in this case, the code would loop 1000 times. Is there any simpler (and elegant) way to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: Do you need a first role for a user or _any_ role will do?

Answer (score 1):

i assume that user-roles is a one-many relationship, then you can get first/last role each user with one query (postgres/mysql):

```rb
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  scope :first_each_user, ->(sort) {
    from(
      <<~SQL
      (
        SELECT roles.*, 
        row_number() OVER (
         PARTITION BY roles.user_id 
         ORDER BY roles.created_at #{sort.to_s}
        ) AS rn
        FROM roles
      ) roles
      SQL
    ).where("roles.rn = 1")
  }
end

# first
Role.first_each_user(:asc)
# last
Role.first_each_user(:desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your query like this way. Still have to loop over users.

```
User.includes(:roles).find_each do |user|
  puts user.roles[0] #First Role
  puts user.roles[-1] #Last Role
end
```

If you dont want to do a loop, you can create foreign keys for first and last Role in your "users" table and update them every time a new role is created. The query should be like

```
User.includes(:first_role, :last_role)
```